# How to obtain the descending order (ordinality) of an integer array?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to find the descending order of the elements in an array of integers.

Example:

If I have an array:

```
x = {24, 55, 22, 1}
```

I want an algorithm in C that results in array `order` where:

```
order = {2, 1, 3, 4}
```

Considering that 'my' array `x` can become rather large (from 1k-1M), my question is as follows: How do I get the `order` array as efficiently (fast) as possible?
Clearly there must exist an efficient algorithm that does that already?

Comment: By "vector", do you mean array? C++ has a type `vector` in its standard library; C does  not. (gcc also has an unrelated extension called [vectors](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), unrelated to C++'s `std::vector`.)

Comment: I meant array of course. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the comparator function of the qsort standard function:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm
Just implement your comparator to add an indirection, ie replace:

```
return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
```

by

```
return (x[*(int*)b] - x[*(int*)a]);
```

(edit to get descending order)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int x[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };
int indexes[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( x[*(int*)b] - x[*(int*)a] );
}

int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", indexes[n]);
   }

   qsort(indexes, 5, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", indexes[n]);
   }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a bit since I didnt get it to work when I tested it on the sample code?

Comment: Thanks now I understand. It always helps with an example.

Comment: Using subtraction, like your `return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );`, in a `qsort` comparison function risks problems with overflow (consider if `a` is a large negative number and `b` is a large positive number).

Answer (score 5):

I guess the more efficient way is the best known way. Eg:

- allocate a vector for all indices from 0 up to N-1 and initialize it
- sort the indices vector by using one of the efficient sorting algorithms eg [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) but by referring to the original data vector (you sort indices, you compare original data)

Comment: Good answer. Just to add some additional info: this method is O(n*log(n)), and it can't get any better than that as it is bounded by the sorting operation.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves - where, how were you able to determine this type of efficiency rating? (i.e. _O(n*log(n)_).  Do you have a link?

Comment: @ryyker Well, since quicksort and mergesort both run in O(n*log(n)), that's the complexity of the whole algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

I would start with [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) from stdlib.h
Since it takes a pointer to function, will not be the fastest, but is surely the easier to code.

```
int v[4] = {24, 55, 22, 1};
int fcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int A = *(const int*)a;
    int B = *(const int*)b;
    if (v[A] > v[B]) return -1;
    if (v[A] < v[B]) return +1;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3 };
    qsort(r, 4, sizeof(int), fcmp);
}
```